# Android could not detect image orientation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, samsung-mobile

I have an issue in Samsung Galaxy Device. I take a picture by call `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`. My code work correctly in another device but in Samsung Galaxy S3 Device, It could not detect the orientation of this picture. The pictures give back to my app are rotated horizontal but when i save it and open it by another app (default gallery android app for example) it work so true.
This's my code:

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, KEY_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

And:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == KEY_TAKE_PHOTO&& resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // TODO: View this image
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the orientation of the picture taken is not what you want it to be?

Comment: Oh yes! My mind is the orientation of the picture taken.

Comment: Why not just do a check if the width is large than the height and if it is rotate it?

Comment: Oh sorry but this picture may be landscape or portrait. I care about something in this picture, it must real. For example when i take the picture, my friend alway lie down.